# How to take the value select and insert into SQL via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

**GOAL:** select an option and take its value via ajax and insert into the query.
thanks for the help.

**bugs_cards.php**

```
<div class="filtros-categoria-sistema">
                <select id="session" name="session"  class="form-control">
                  <option value='' selected >Selecione o Sistema</option>
                  <option value='00000000001'>teste 1</option>
                  <option value='00000000002'>teste 2</option>
                </select> 
              </div>
```

**SQL**

```
if (isset($_POST['workselected1'])) {
  $workselected = $_POST['workselected1'];
}


$SyntaxTransactionRotas = "SELECT * FROM sup_cad_bugs_cards where painel_COD = $workselected AND card_status = 'EN' AND card_nome $nome AND card_tipo_COD $categoria  ";
```

**AJAX**

```
   $('#session').on('change', function(e){
    var workselected = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "bugs_cards.php",
      data: {workselected1: workselected},
      cache:false,
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: What's the specific issue? At a guess you need quotes around the values you include in the SQL statement, and `=` operators before the values in the `where` clause. The main thing you should note that your PHP is ***wide open*** to SQL injection attacks. You should change that logic to use prepared statements instead.

Comment: the problem and that when selecting option 1, the value 00000000001 not sent via ajax to the PHP variable to be inserted into SQL and perform the query . in this case the where clause query should be "SELECT * FROM sup_cad_bugs_cards WHERE painel_COD = 00000000001 ..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following sql query:

```sql
$SyntaxTransactionRotas = "SELECT * FROM `sup_cad_bugs_cards` where `painel_COD` = '$workselected' AND `card_status` = 'EN' AND `card_nome` =  '$nome' AND `card_tipo_COD` = '$categoria'  ";
```

**TIP**: Try to use **prepared statements** as this sql query is prone to **sql injections**.